# ¿Cómo tomar una muestra de un DataFrame con una media y desviación estándar dadas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, scikit-learn, ciencia-de-datos

Tengo un DataFrame con unos 2 millones de filas, necesito saber cuántos cluster representa. Para ello aplicaré el siguiente código:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

X = train[features[3:]]
y = train['action']

# Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer
model = KMeans()
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(
    model, k=(4,12), metric='calinski_harabasz', timings=False, locate_elbow=False
)

visualizer.fit(X)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()        # Finalize and render the figure
```

El problema es que, para obtener el número de clústeres de 2 millones de observaciones, es imposible con los recursos de los que dispongo. Por ello, quería tomar una muestra del 10% que tenga la misma distribución normal con la media y desviación estándar tomadas de una de las variables del DataFrame.

¿Alguien me puede explicar como tomar 200.000 observaciones que tengan la misma media y desviación?

Comment: Si estás usando `make_blobs` no devuelve un `DataFrame` devuelve un `array` de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema en matemáticas es como escoger una muestra representativa de la población [muestra estadística](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muestra_estad%C3%ADstica). Aunque hay varios [métodos de muestreo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrategias_de_muestreo), uno de los más usados, más sencillos, y con mejores resultados es el **muestreo aleatorio simple**.

El muestreo aleatorio simple consiste en escoger un número de datos *N* de forma aleatoria, este número *N* se puede determinar según el **tamaño del universo** (población), el **error máximo** aceptado, etc. Como explicar esto me desviaría de la pregunta planteada te lo dejo aquí: [Tamaño de la muestra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tama%C3%B1o_de_la_muestra)

Vamos a demostrar todo esto, usando parte de tu código:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

#Nos creamos un conjunto de datos tamaño (2.000.000, 2)
X, y = make_blobs(2_000_000, random_state=2020) #Uso random state para tener la misma semilla
print("Media:\t\t\t", X.mean())
print("Desviación típica:\t", X.std())
```

**Salida:**

```
Media:               0.6510469396034795
Desviación típica:   6.018726320373567
```

Genial esta es la media y desviación típica de nuestros datos, ahora vamos a escoger una muestra aleatoria, para ello vamos a usar `numpy.random.randint` para generar aleatorios enteros.

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2_000_000, size=10_000)
print("Media:\t\t\t", X[idx].mean())
print("Desviación típica:\t", X[idx].std())
```

**Salida:**

```
Media:               0.6576014984171598
Desviación típica:   6.012554650434753
```

*(Esta parte si es aleatoria, para que puedas comprobar distintas muestras)*

#### Explicación código

- La función `np.random.randint()` con los parámetros `low` y `high` le indicamos que escoga números aleatorios en un rango de cero a 2M (el número de datos que tenemos)
- Después con el parámetro `size` le indicamos el número de datos que queremos escoger, en este caso lo que sera nuestra muestra, `10_000`. Puedes ponerla de 200.000 si quieres tener menos error, pero no habrá una gran diferencia.
- Por último mediante **indexing** extraemos los índices que han sido generados anteiormente de forma aleatoria `X[idx]`

#### Conclusiones

En este caso yo he escogido un tamaño de muestra de 10.000, escoge el valor que más se adapte a tus necesidades. Ten en cuenta que cuanto mayor sea la muestra menor será el [error muestral](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_muestral), pero que este incremento, si ves toda la **documentación aportada anteriormente**, te darás cuenta que **no guarda una relacción directa**.

Poniendo un ejemplo claro, cuanto más alta es la muestra con, incrementos en su tamaño bestiales, solo reducirás un 0.1% el error.